# Auto completion for classes on React Tailwind CSS app not appearing in WebStorm

Tags: reactjs, webstorm, tailwind-css

Pretty simple yet frustrating question. I've started working on an React app using Tailwind CSS but the Tailwind CSS autocompletion/suggestions isn't appearing.

The JetBrains demo shows the wanted result. [Tailwind CSS | WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/tailwind-css.html)

But, in my WebStorm I can't get the autocompletion and suggestions on classes to appear. Tailwind CSS is functioning fine, it's just the autocompletion that doesn't want to show up.

Since there's no error of any kind I am kinda lost here, so any help into the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This may depend on how you have set it up / configured it (e.g. having `jit` mode one: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-50318 or when in subfolder https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-48964 .. or perhaps something else (need details on your setup): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB?q=tailwind). Anyway: please try [2021.2 Beta version](https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2021/07/webstorm-2021-2-beta/) and see how it goes (you can run it in parallel to your current 2021.1 version; just do not open the same project in both versions at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a problem with the current Tailwindcss version..

switching back to **npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.1.4** did the trick.
Hope this helps someone else who's stuck aswell!

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-51405 -- marked as fixed earlier today .. so should be in the next major 2021.2 version.

Comment: Experienced the same issue with Angular 13 and Tailwind 3. Solution for me was to update to the latest WebStorm version (2021.3.1).

Answer (score -5):

Just install the **Tailwind CSS IntelliSense** extension in vsCode itself. No need to downgrade.

Comment: This question is not about vscode.